# how to get access to $ methodes in angular2 via typescript

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

i want to create a simple clock app, that will show me the current time. 
for doing this I'm using typescript and angular2.

my problem is that angular2 does not respond to Window.setinterval methode and I need to use $interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]); methode.

but i dont know how to access the '$' methodes in typescript.

my code:

```
 clockString:string = '00:00:010';
constructor()
{
 // ?
}
Tick () 
{  
 this.clockString=Date.now().toString();          
}
```

Thank you,
aria.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 has gotten rid of the `$` methods and I'm fairly certain the $interval as well. Just use the normal javascript `setInterval` method to create ticks and if you have to look up `ngZone` to get angular to detect changes. Cheers!